# Sbt can't find SbtScalariform

Tags: scala, sbt

**plugins.sbt**:

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.0-SNAPSHOT")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalaxb" % "sbt-scalaxb" % "1.1.2")
```

the part of `Build.scala`:

```
lazy val formatSettings = SbtScalariform.scalariformSettings ++ Seq(
    ScalariformKeys.preferences in Compile := formattingPreferences,
    ScalariformKeys.preferences in Test    := formattingPreferences
  )
```

sbt version is 0.13. And the error is "`not found: value SbtScalariform`". What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

Use 1.1.0 instead.

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.1.0")`

Comment: `[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.1.0: not found`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my Build.scala:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform.scalariformSettings

lazy val proj = Project("app", file("."),
  settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ scalariformSettings ++ Seq(...))
```

Hope this helps future users. The README had the import wrong.