# sbt-scalariform plugin - can't resolve settings

Tags: scala, sbt, scalariform

I wanted to integrate `scalariform` tool into `SBT`. Following the https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform/tree/master I created `plugins.sbt` file with line

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.3.0")
```

then I created `scalariform.sbt` file with

```
scalariformSettings
```

Here I am stuck, when I try to run `SBT` for my project I am getting

```
scalariform.sbt:1: error: not found: value scalariformSettings
```

I also tried

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform

SbtScalariform.scalariformSettings
```

in `scalariform.sbt` but then I am getting

```
scalariform.sbt:1: error: object typesafe is not a member of package com
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform
           ^
scalariform.sbt:3: error: not found: value SbtScalariform
SbtScalariform.scalariformSettings
^
```

I saw the thread [Sbt can't find SbtScalariform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558696/sbt-cant-find-sbtscalariform) but it suggest changing the version to (`1.1.0`). Even if this worked (and it does not) I would prefer `1.3.0` version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your plugin file in the correct location? For SBT 0.13.x, I have the following working:

in `build.sbt`

```
import scalariform.formatter.preferences._

name := "app"

organization := "example"

version := "0.0.0"

libraryDependencies += // ...

scalariformSettings

ScalariformKeys.preferences := ScalariformKeys.preferences.value
  .setPreference(RewriteArrowSymbols, true)
  .setPreference(AlignParameters, true)
  .setPreference(AlignSingleLineCaseStatements, true)
  .setPreference(PlaceScaladocAsterisksBeneathSecondAsterisk, true)
  .setPreference(MultilineScaladocCommentsStartOnFirstLine, true)
```

in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.3.0")
```

Comment: Ok, that is strange. I copy-pasted your snippet w/o the part with configuration modification and removed import statement (so basically I just added `scalariformSettings` to my `build.sbt`) and now it works. The only issue left is that `IDEA` complains that it can't find symbol `scalariformSettings`.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you about IDEA.

Comment: Yes, the crucial line is the `scalariformSettings` in the `build.sbt` file.  After adding it I have now `scalariformFormat` task in the sbt.