# IDEA and scalariform configuration - unresolved symbols even if scalariform works from command line

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

This question is partially related to [sbt-scalariform plugin - can't resolve settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585429/sbt-scalariform-plugin-cant-resolve-settings). I managed to run `scalariform` from command line as `SBT` task.

Now the problem is with `IDEA`. When I open my `build.sbt`, which looks like this:

```
import scalariform.formatter.preferences._

name := """scheduling-backend"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"

resolvers += "spray nightlies" at "http://nightlies.spray.io"

resolvers += "SpringSource Milestone Repository" at "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"

resolvers += "Neo4j Cypher DSL Repository" at "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.0" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % "2.3.0",
  "io.spray" % "spray-can" % "1.3.0",
  "io.spray" % "spray-routing" % "1.3.0",
  "io.spray" % "spray-testkit" % "1.3.0" % "test",
  "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.2.5",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.14" % "test",
  "org.springframework.scala" % "spring-scala" % "1.0.0.M2",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "3.0.0.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-rest" % "3.0.0.RELEASE",
  "javax.validation" % "validation-api" % "1.1.0.Final",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "0.8.0",
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "2.0.1" % "test" classifier "tests",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.9",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-language:_",
  "-target:jvm-1.7",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8"
)

org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.Settings

scalariformSettings

ScalariformKeys.preferences := ScalariformKeys.preferences.value
  .setPreference(AlignParameters, true)
  .setPreference(CompactControlReadability, true)
```

IDEA reports problems with my file.

I am getting `Cannot resolve symbol scalariformSettings` and `Cannot resolve symbol ScalariformKeys`even if I everything works from terminal.

Comment: I've yet to have a build file with an sbt plugin to open in IntelliJ IDEA 13 without errors. Maybe we should log an issue. :)

Comment: Well my original build file generated by typesafe activator did not report any errors, probably because it was pretty simple :P. Thanks for letting me know that I am not the only one. I will raise an issue in coming days then.

Comment: ahh, I copy-pasted your build.sbt without removing dependencies and ended up downloading the internet for half an hour :(

Comment: @DenisTulskiy :D, oh those dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform._` to `build.sbt` seems to fix the error on 13.1.1 with scala plugin 0.33.403, but I have to admit it ignored the import at first and then randomly started to see it.

Comment: I tried adding this import also, but after that my sbt stopped working from command line, does it work for you?

Comment: My bad, I had to do something different. After adding the line you mentioned both `SBT` and `IDEA` are behaving correctly, thanks!